# fadeOut contents than slideToggle element itself

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to first do a `.fadeOut()` on a div's contents, then I'd like to `.slideToggle()` the div shut. I've tried a couple of things:

```
$('#followUp').contents().fadeOut(650);
$('#followUp').delay(650).slideToggle();

$('#followUp').contents().fadeOut(function(){
    $('#followUp').delay(650).slideToggle();
})
```

Neither of the above are working. How can I get this to work please? Thank you!

Comment: What's the markup of the "followUp" element?

Comment: what is the exact effect you want? doing it simultaneously or one by one?

Comment: please provide a sample in jsfiddle

Comment: @T.J.Crowder #followUp is a simple div with a number of elements within.

Comment: @Orentet I'd like the two effects to be staggered, so the contents first fadeOut then the div slides shut. I don't know how it'll look yet so there may need to be some overlap between them (i.e. div starts sliding towards the end of the fadeOut but before it's entirely complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example mostly works if the markup within the "followUp" div consists of *elements* rather than just text nodes, but fails on Firefox because jQuery tries to call `getComputedStyle` on any text nodes. Rather than `contents()`, you want to use `children()` or use `"#followUp *"` as the selector (thank you scessor for pointing that out in the comments under [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8816029/157247)).

The problem with fading out the contents, though, is that unless you do something to counter it, the div will then be without height and snap shut rather than sliding shut as you wanted. My solution to that is to fade to *nearly* invisible but not quite:

So given:

```
<div id="followUp">
    <div>Contents</div>
    <div>Click anywhere on these contents to trigger the effect</div>
</div>
```

Then:

```
var followUp = $('#followUp');
followUp.children().animate({
  opacity: 0.1,
  duration: 650
});
followUp.delay(650).slideToggle();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ejelum)

(I wouldn't use your second example (the completion callback) because the completion callback will fire once for *every element* contained by the "followUp" div, which is clearly not what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
$('#followUp *').fadeOut(650);
$('#followUp').delay(650).slideToggle();
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xfmm/6/).

Comment: That will make the div fade out, then reappear with the `slideToggle`. The OP clearly said they wanted the `slideToggle` to *shut* the div.

Comment: Your updated answer is effectively the same as the OP's first option using `contents`.

Comment: And the `.contents()`-version throws javascript errors (also your examples), my updated version works without errors.

Comment: Not on Chrome or IE. I just tested in Firefox and indeed it's throwing some kind of error, will look into it. Odd that yours doesn't -- but it also doesn't show a slide effect when shutting the div.

Comment: Ah, yes, the difference between `$("#followUp *")` and `$("#followUp").contents()` is that the latter will include text and comment nodes; the former won't. So definitely part of the solution. +1 for that bit.

Comment: I've corrected mine now. It no longer causes issues in Firefox, and also does the slide-up.

Comment: There are no problems with the slide-up in my version (my example tested with firefox, chrome and ie8).

Comment: *"There are no problems with the slide-up in my version"* There were when I tested it. I suspect it's a timing thing. I bet if you start the slideup even just a few milliseconds earlier, it'll go away. That would be one of three ways to ensure it works correctly (another being mine, and another being Yoshi's). All sorts of ways to solve this. :-)

Comment: Timing? Do you mean, if the 2nd animation starts before the first has finished? You can do both animations at the same time (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xfmm/7/)).

Comment: I mean that if the first finishes, the contents of the div become completely invisible (`display: none`) and so the div doesn't have any height anymore (barring CSS to the contrary). So for the slide to work, it has to start before that happens. By giving 650 for both the fade and the delay, it may or may not depending on the vagaries of what's going on. My solution is to avoid having the contents completely disappear. Yoshi's is to explicitly set a height on the div. I was saying yours might be to make sure the slide starts a few milliseconds before the end of the fade.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.when(
  $('#followUp').css({
    height: $('#followUp').height()
  }).find('*').fadeOut(650)
).then(function () {
  $('#followUp').slideToggle();
});
```

Maybe?

Alternate version (with a little hint from zdrsh):

```
$('#followUp').css('height', '+=0px').children().fadeOut(650).promise().done(function () {
  $('#followUp').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: No, because the queued callback will execute repeatedly (once for every element within the "followUp" div). Granted it's relatively harmless since you used `slideUp` rather than `slideToggle`, but still.

Comment: Much appreciated Yoshi, although it feels a little indirect to me, if you know what I mean...

Comment: @Yoshi: That's interesting. I didn't know a jQuery instance could be passed into `when` (and I can't find it documented, in a couple of minutes of searching). But it seems to work: http://jsbin.com/ugutid/3

Comment: @T.J.Crowder From my understanding it's that because the elements passed to `when` are animated, they are deferred objects and thus valid for when. @sscirrus Sorry, don't exactly know what you mean ;)

Comment: +1 but you need to change `contents` to `children`, see the discussion on scessor's answer (or the content of my answer) for why.